# how do I multiply a command argument with a constant?

Tags: formatting, calculations, lettrine

I'm writing a novel and I defined a set of commands for starting a new chapter:

```
%A
\newcommand{\AKapitel}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=-0.2,findent=-22pt, nindent=14pt, loversize=0.26,slope=9pt]{A}{#1}}

%B
\newcommand{\BKapitel}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=-0.2,findent=-9pt, nindent=5pt, loversize=0.26,slope=1pt]{B}{#1}}

%D
\newcommand{\DKapitel}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=-0.2,findent=-8pt, nindent=7pt, loversize=0.26,slope=-4pt]{D}{#1}}
```

This way, I don't have to write out the lettrine parameters all the time. Works pretty well. But when I pick a different format (a4 instead of a5) or a different base font size, it gets messed up. So here is what I want to do: define a constant as factor and multiply all the parameters with it. Something like in this pseudocode:

```
scalefactor := 0.87
\newcommand{\AKapitel}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=-0.2*scalefactor,findent=-22pt*scalefactor, nindent=14pt*scalefactor, loversize=0.26*scalefactor,slope=9pt*scalefactor]{A}{#1}}
```

How do I do this in actual latex code? Sorry for my limited knowledge about latex, I'm learning by doing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I suggest the macros from the `calculator` package

Answer (score 4):

It is easier for the keys expecting a `<dimen>`. For those expecting a decimal, you need something extra, as this is not implemented in core `LaTeX`. I do it here with package [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). Indeed its macros are expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand\scalefactor {0.87}

\newcommand{\AKapitel}[1]{%
  \lettrine[lines=3,
  lraise=\xintRound {4}{\xinttheexpr-0.2*\scalefactor\relax},
  findent=\scalefactor\dimexpr-22pt\relax, 
  nindent=\scalefactor\dimexpr 14pt\relax,
  loversize=\xintRound {4}{\xinttheexpr 0.26*\scalefactor\relax},
  slope=\scalefactor\dimexpr 9pt\relax]{A}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\AKapitel {nd} hier ist ein Beispiel (Scale factor=\scalefactor).

\vspace{1.5cm}

\renewcommand\scalefactor {.5}

\AKapitel {nd} hier ist ein Beispiel (Scale factor=\scalefactor).

\vspace{1.5cm}
\renewcommand\scalefactor {.4176}

\AKapitel {nd} hier ist ein Beispiel (Scale factor=\scalefactor).

\vspace{1.5cm}
\renewcommand\scalefactor {.2}

\AKapitel {nd} hier ist ein Beispiel (Scale factor=\scalefactor).

\end{document}
```

> [image: multiply constant]

Rather than `xintexpr` one may make do here with loading only `xintfrac` and then like `loversize=\xintRound {4}{\xintMul {-0.26}{\scalefactor}}` etc..